# Local variables and elif

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to know why the compiler writes:

> local variable 'randomindexmother1' referenced before assignment

I have been searching and I do not need to treat the randomindexfather1 as a global variable. Therefore, I think that is a mater of the elif statements.

```
def generation(listPaths):
    # This function will give us the new generation of kids
    # we will introduce the survived paths
    # This function will take as input the list sorted paths and sorted fitnesses of each path
    # listP will be a list produced in a while statmentself.
    rand1 = 0
    rand2 = 0
    lunusedindex = []
    newpaths = []
    i = 0
    fpoint = listPaths[0][0][0]
    lpoint = listPaths[0][0][-1]
    mother = []
    father = []
    kid1 = []
    srtlist = []
    # this is going to be the random number between the fitness of the maximum path fitness and the minimum of
    # the half population
    leng = len(listPaths)
    lunusedindex = range(leng)
    while i < leng / 2:
        # here we select an aleatory father and an aleatory mother
        rand1 = random.choice(lunusedindex)
        rand2 = random.choice(lunusedindex)
        if rand1 == rand2:
            while rand1 == rand2:
                rand1 = random.choice(lunusedindex)
        # here we delete the mother and the father selected to not repeat a father and mother
        del lunusedindex[rand1]
        if rand1 < rand2:
            del lunusedindex[rand2 - 1]
        else:
            del lunusedindex[rand2]
        k = 0
        while k < 2:
            mother = copy.deepcopy(listPaths[rand1][0])
            father = copy.deepcopy(listPaths[rand2][0])
            del mother[0]
            del mother[-1]
            del father[0]
            del father[-1]
            indexfather = range(len(father))
            indexmother = range(len(mother))
            kid1.append(fpoint)
            j = 0
            ref = 0
            rem = 0
            while j < len(father) or len(mother):
                # with this statment we ensuring that less points are going to be repeated and if mother or father
                # become empty, this means that all the points are used but some of them can be repeated
                if len(indexfather) <= 2:
                    randomindexfather1 = random.randint(indexfather[0], indexfather[1 - ref])
                    del indexfather[0:randomindexfather1 + 1]
                    ref += 1
                    if len(indexfather) == 0:
                        randomindexfather2 = randomindexfather1 + 1
                    else:
                        randomindexfather2 = random.randint(indexfather[0], indexfather[1 - ref])

                elif len(indexmother) <= 2:
                    randomindexmother1 = random.randint(indexmother[0], indexmother[1 - rem])
                    del indexmother[0:randomindexmother1 + 1]
                    rem += 1
                    if len(indexmother) == 0:
                        randomindexmother2 = randomindexmother1 + 1
                    else:
                        randomindexmother2 = random.randint(indexmother[0], indexmother[1 - rem])

                elif len(indexfather) > 2:
                    randomindexfather1 = random.randint(indexfather[0], (len(indexfather) - 2))
                    del indexfather[0:randomindexfather1 + 1]
                    randomindexfather2 = random.randint(indexfather[0], (len(indexfather) - 1))

                elif len(indexmother) > 2:
                    randomindexmother1 = random.randint(indexmother[0], (len(indexmother) - 2))
                    del indexmother[0:randomindexmother1 + 1]
                    randomindexmother2 = random.randint(indexmother[0], (len(indexmother) - 1))

                kid1.extend(father[randomindexfather1:randomindexfather2])
                kid1.extend(mother[randomindexmother1:randomindexmother2])
                del father[randomindexfather1:randomindexfather2]
                del mother[randomindexmother1:randomindexmother2]
                j += 1
                # with this code we take parts of the parents until they will be empty,the problem is that points are going to be repeated
            kid1.append(lpoint)
            for x in kid1:
                inde = random.uniform(0, len(kid1) - 1)
                if kid1[inde] in kid1:
                    del kid1[inde]
            distances = []
            totdist = 0
            z = 1
            while z < len(kid1) - 1:
                # menys 1 ja que tenim len(kid1)-1 intervals
                distances.append(distpoint(kid1[z - 1], kid1[z]))
                totdist = sum(distances)
            newpaths.append([kid1, totdist])
            k += 1
        i += 1
    srtlist = sorted(newpaths, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    return srtlist

x = [[[[3, 4], [2, 4], [5, 8], [2, 4], [4, 5]], 5], [[[3, 4], [6, 8], [4, 6], [6, 4], [4, 5]], 4]]
Y = generation(x)
print Y
```

Answer (score 3):

You have execution paths that doesn't set `randomindexmother1` uses it nonetheless. Assume `len(indexfather) <= 2` then you don't execute the other clauses and hit `kid1.extend(mother[randomindexmother1:randomindexmother2])` without setting the variable. Looks like a bug in your program logic.

Comment: So, how should I solve the problem with the elif statement. I need to differentiate this 4 case.

Comment: That will depend on what you are trying to achieve with that block of logic, either define defaults for those variables or change the logic such that you don't use them before assigning a value.

Comment: I am trying to change the logic such that I don't use them before assigning a value